# Simple PHP Dom Parser Can't Access

Tags: php, html, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

I am trying to access one of the turkish ministry of health websites: I've parsed the news from the rest, but this one I can't reach. I've tried many other tricks but when I try this, it gets stuck and won't return and the website freezes in that part and doesn't load the rest of my website after that part.

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.tkhk.gov.tr/TR,6/duyurular.html');
$i = 0;
foreach($html->find('a.belge_alt_b') as $element){
echo "
<a href=\"http://www.tkhk.gov.tr".$element->href." \">". $element->plaintext ."</a>
";   
$i++ ;
if($i > 3) break;
}
```

I've used the same method with the others, too as I said, but this one seems to be a problem. Can this be caused by their servers or not?

Comment: I tested the code with [simplehtmldom_1_5.zip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/latest/download?source=files) and it works fine.

Comment: i've tried in another server after you told me this, it has worked for me too, but in my main it doesn't work. but as i said, for the rest of the websites where i parse the news it works in all servers.

Comment: found the error, Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 8388608 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 41 bytes)

changed the memory limit problem solved.

`ini_set('memory_limit', '32M');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those whom may experience that;

Check your allowed memory size and debug your script, use the code below at the top of your script and try again.

```
echo 'display_errors = ' . ini_get('memory_limit') . "\n";  // this will show your maximum allowed memory usage
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); // for error reporting
ini_set('display_errors', 1); // for error reporting
```

if you get some error like

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 8388608 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 41 bytes)
```

Then change the memory limit as you wish.

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '32M');
```